# Insert and Select Performance on SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

We have an SQL Server with pretty big tables (but not humongous) - maybe 30-40 million records each.

We need to

a) insert approx 1000 records per second (on certain times - but we cant batch insert) to one of those tables, say TABLE_A and
b) at the same time select * from TABLE_B where id = _SOME_GUID_ID

I have noticed that (a) currently takes 500-600 ms under load (per insert given that we can't batch them) and (b) takes approximately 400ms (there is an index)

This is nowhere near the performance we are looking for. Is there any way to optimize those tables / operations?

The current server has 16gb of ram and the total database size is approximately 40gb. We expect those tables to become 10x as big in the next few months. Is there any sort of sharding we can do with Sql Server? Would we see any performance improvements using the MySQL Percona build?

Hopefully this makes sense. I wanted to add that we are using NHibernate but the performance stated above is milliseconds spent inserting to the db - not including the application or nh overhead.

Thanks,
Yannis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things come to mind. What is the primary key is it a GUID or integer, if it is a GUID and you clustered on that then SQL Server will have to insert in many different places instead of sequentially. Is you database sized, is your log sized or do they autogrow all the time, see [Sizing database files](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBAdmin/MSSQLServerAdmin/sizing-database-files)

Run profiler and see what kind of  SQL nhibernate creates.
1000 inserts per second is not that impressive anymore, the bottleneck will probably be hardware as well, make sure that it is properly sized and configured. Are tempdb, log and data files on the same drive? If so, move them to separate drives

Another option is to rewrite the piece that does these inserts and batch them instead of single row inserts

Here is an example I ran from SSMS, it does 4999 inserts in 166 milliseconds, 1000 in 40 milliseconds

```
CREATE TABLE Sometest(id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
SomeCol VARCHAR(200), SomeDate DATETIME,SomeCol2 VARCHAR(200), 
SomeDate2 DATETIME,SomeCol3 VARCHAR(200), 
SomeDate3 DATETIME,SomeCol4 VARCHAR(200), SomeDate4 DATETIME)
GO




DECLARE @start DATETIME = GETDATE()
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @id INT =1
WHILE @id < 1000
BEGIN
    INSERT Sometest
    SELECT @id ,'BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla111111',GETDATE(),
    'BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla2222',GETDATE(),
    'BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla3333',GETDATE(),
    'BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla4444',GETDATE()
SET @id+=1
END




SELECT DATEDIFF(ms,@start,GETDATE())
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Sometest
```

If you wrap the whole thing in a transaction it will be much faster, 50000 inserts in 800 milliseconds, 5000 inserts in 103 milliseconds, 1000 inserts in 23 milliseconds

```
TRUNCATE TABLE Sometest
DECLARE @start DATETIME = GETDATE()
SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN tran
DECLARE @id INT =1
WHILE @id < 50000
BEGIN
    INSERT Sometest
    SELECT @id ,'BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla111111',GETDATE(),
    'BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla2222',GETDATE(),
    'BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla3333',GETDATE(),
    'BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla4444',GETDATE()
SET @id+=1
END
commit
SELECT DATEDIFF(ms,@start,GETDATE())
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Sometest
```

Run something like that on your system with a table that looks like your table and investigate what the problem is, maybe you need to presize files, separate files, defragment the tables etc etc etc

Comment: TABLE_A has an auto-increment int ID and TABLE_B has a guid id. How long should one insert take in such (quite heavily indexed) tables given our hardware then?

Comment: Run your inserts from SSMS and test, how do you know what your problem is without testing...could be the network, the drives. What is your physical layout, how much RAM can SQL Server see etc etc. What does your performance test plan look like

Answer (score 0):

Your Guid could be a sequential guid or a random guid, you need to know which. You can temporarily disable non clustered indexes and rebuild them at the end of the insert, providing you dont mind (possibly) slower selects on that table for that period. How many cores and how many temp dbs have you got? Try 1 tempdb per core (upto 8 cores) but be sure to have the correct trace falg set to equalize tempdb usage. And as said below, batch your inserts